# How to call template with parameter(with default vvalue) in xsl file?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

In following template call

```
  <xsl:call-template name="My_Class">
    <xsl:with-param name="className" select="getClassName()"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="baseClassName" select="??????"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
```

i have to call My_Class template with value of second parameter i.e. baseClass as user defined. i.e. suppose i want call this template by passing value of second argument(shown as ???? in above code) as "balaji".
Any suggestion on above? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to pass a parameter as a fixed, you can just do something like this:

```
<xsl:call-template name="My_Class">
    <xsl:with-param name="className" select="getClassName()"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="baseClassName" select="'balaji'"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

Alternatively, you could specify the value as a default value in the template itself

```
<xsl:call-template name="My_Class">
    <xsl:with-param name="className" select="getClassName()"/>
</xsl:call-template> 

<xsl:template name="My_Class">
   <xsl:param name="className" />
   <xsl:param name="baseClassName" select="'Balaji'" />
   <xsl:value-of select="$baseClassName" />
</xsl:template>
```

Is this what you are were looking for?